# What is the purpose of this cage on the wall of hotel room?

Tags: hotels, morocco

I'm looking for ideas about functionality of this wooden "cage" found on the wall of hotel room in Fez, Morocco. I haven't had a chance to ask the service about it, and I'm yet to find a similar thing in any other hotel.

The photo was taken in 2019. The cage is about 50 x 50 cm, has a lock on the side and opens sideways I believe. During my stay it was empty and closed all the time. Notice it has no back panel - the wallpaper behind is visible - so my guess is nothing dirty (like laundry) goes inside.

**Edit:** The hotel in the question is Hotel Mounia Fes. I found a fair number of other pictures from the place on Google Maps and Tripadvisor that feature this cage ([example one](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/0a/00/28/a7/hotel-mounia.jpg)). The takeaways for me, regarding the comments you made, are:

- the thing may be smaller than I stated, like 30 to 40 cm on the side;
- it's not clear whether every room is equipped with it, but certainly more than one;
- location of the cage varies from room to room;
- it can open left- or right-side (the linked photo shows mirrored version with visible hinge).

[image: A wooden cage found on the wall of hotel room in Fez, Morocco]

Comment: Looks like a towel rack at the first glance to me, but it's probably not one. Where was this placed in your room/suite?

Comment: It was placed next to the bed - in the lower left corner of the photo you can see fragment of the nightstand - but it feels more like "hang it anywhere it fits" than it's functionally attached to the bed. About the towels - I can't see this suitable for drying, but I do can imagine some fresh ones are stuck between the horizontal bars. But then, why would it be openable?

Comment: Maybe it's meant to be used opened to hold laundry or towels

Comment: E.g. https://www.organizerfurniture.com/products/Wholesale-bathroom-wall-mounted-wood-shelf-towel-rack-for-clothing-shop-display-foldable.html

Comment: There is something like a screw on the left side which does not appear to do anything. Is there a bracket on the inside, and it folds out upwards?

Comment: @WeatherVane the thing on the left side is a key lock and, by its position, I was assuming the whole thing folds out rightwards, like a door - althought it's not for sure, as I didn't get a key to open it.

Comment: @zhantongz the rack you linked to is pretty similar to my "cage", I'm only worried my one opens sideways. I'd welcome this as a correct answer if someone confirmed this from hotel experience. So far, I like the guesswork from everybody!

Comment: Presumably, then, you can see a hinge on the right side?

Comment: If it actually was a rack for drying clothes, it would not make sense to have a lock on it, have the bars rotated at different angles, nor so close to eachother and the curved shape would be disadvantageous. I doubt that it is the correct guess.

Comment: The key lock on the side suggests it might be a protective/don't-mess-with-it cover for a thermostat. But I don't see a thermostat inside.

Comment: Does it exist in other rooms of the hotel?

Comment: Maybe it was created to get people to ask questions about it on the internet and advertise the hotel? :)

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica indeed, there's nothing behind the cage, just a wall. Also no idea about existence of this equipment in other rooms.

Comment: @JonathanReez that would be funny, but it really looks like having _some_ utility.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm convinced it had a hinge on the right side, although I saw it over a year ago and have no other photos.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yeah, I also think the spacing between the bars is too tight for the rack/hanger function. Regarding the rotation of the bars - I believe they were placed evenly when the thing was made, and what we see in the picture is result of wear and tear, like the joints between frame and the bars loosened a bit so they now are turned in different directions.

Comment: If there is a lock and not a simple catch, then it must be a safe :-)

Comment: That looks like a magazine or newspaper rack placed conveniently for bedside reading material.  Of course nobody reads anything but their cellphones now, so it was empty.  A vestigial artifact of a long forgotten era!

Comment: If it really is a towel or newspaper rack, then the hinges could be so that the staff can open it to dust the inside. And the lock could be because guests would otherwise mess around with it and perhaps break the hinges.

Comment: Can you remember the hotel?

Comment: @MarkMayo I've looked up and added name of the hotel to the question.

Comment: Has anyone actually just asked the hotel about it?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes, I emailed them with the address on their site. Alas, the email bounced with the image I included being too large. I've resent, waiting.

Comment: @NateEldredge - know it sounds dumb and this is where we have come the last 30 years... but they used to have newspapers in them locked.   If you were reading the paper during your breakfast you paid 25 cents and grabbed one out of the middle.   (50 cents on sundays)

Comment: @blankip but this is in the guest's private room.  It doesn't make sense to deliver the paper to each guest in a separate device of this sort.

Comment: It's there to lock up curious hotel guests asking the difficult questions. :)

Comment: @phoog - I understand that and it is weird.   It is also weird that you would lock anything up in a flimsy wooden cage with huge gaps.   So I just took the lock out of the equation.   My comment was that I saw the lock used for a specific thing when I saw racks like this.   That's it.    The lock makes no sense in a room, for anything.

Comment: I will bounty the 500 back (I don't care about points) if anyone can get a confirmation from the hotel and put it in the answer.   If they speak English - does anyone know? - I will call them.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure about Morocco but this is your run of the mill newspaper rack.   If you were in a breakfast restaurant in the 60-80s you would likely see this with a different section of the newspaper separated and hung.   These were even at the big double arches.   People may put magazines on them but it was made for newspapers.

It would be normal for a restaurant to get 3 major newspapers and see 15-20 sections strung out all over on this.

**Note:**  Based on the comments around the lock.   Locks were normal and the newspapers were dropped in the middle rolled up.   I don't think the lock was meant to protect the newspapers per se because it is just a flimsy cage with huge holes.   I think the locks were there to convey that what is inside should be paid for.   If I remember right most places left these open with a "pay jar" adjacent.   Some places only provided one newspaper to read and often people that paid left portions of their on the rack after.

I have also heard others comment about this being used to cover a thermostat control.   I have stayed at a lot of hotels and I have never seen one that you could bypass with a long straight coat hanger.   I think that use is debunked.

Comment: Mystery solved!  But while that would make sense in a cafe, why would you put this in a hotel room?  Perhaps the room was once a lounge of some kind?

Comment: If the place was recently updated I would be like "wow that's odd" but if this place was built in the late 80s then this would have been accurate.   And why get rid of it?   You can hang anything on it now.   Ties, shirts, scarves, whatever

Comment: Finally, an answer!

Comment: @lambshaanxy I don't think the mystery is solved.  I've seen these things in hotels before (at least once, though sadly I cannot remember where), and while they superficially resemble a newspaper rack, they do not actually function as one in any practical way, nor are newspaper racks typically used in such a way as to make sense to place one in a hotel room.

Comment: The answer sounds convincing and based on personal experience, but I'd love it to be backed up by some external source, like a photo of such device actually filled with newspapers or, as @mark-mayo tries in the comments, a response right from the source. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I am not convinced. Having the bars arranged in a curved shape and partially on top of eachother would defeat the purpose of a newspaper rack. If you want to hang a newspaper on one of the bars of the pictured device, the other bars would be in the way. Racks for hanging newspapers are similar, but have for practical purposes a quite different arrangement of the bars: https://www.iaprisonind.com/store/p/1596-Newspaper-Rack-Open-Back.aspx

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - why don't you actually find a rack that would be used at a restaurant if you want to refute my answer.   The one that you linked is the ones that were in my library and they are used to house whole newspapers not sections of newspapers.   They are the kind that you check the newspapers out on - the one in the picture is the kind where you see the sections and holds papers in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

**Old fashioned wall mounted drying rack**

Usually wooden devices like this on walls open up and hinge down, and are old fashioned drying racks.

Here is one with arms that open, and is not a lean out rack like the one in your room.

[Clothes Drying Rack - Old Fashion Design Copy](https://www.instructables.com/Clothes-Drying-Rack-Old-Fashion-Design-Copy/)

> It bothered me to see the wife having to work so hard to set up a collapsible drying rack to dry her's and the kids swim stuff so I started researching a wall mount setup that would fold flat against the wall.  Most designs I found were large lean out designs but I needed something with ends sticking out to hold swim caps open to dry. I came across one old antique design that was just what I needed so I took the idea and updated it to my situation. This was a one day construction and then a couple of days of polyurethane stain coats and I was in business.

[Link for photo](https://www.instructables.com/Clothes-Drying-Rack-Old-Fashion-Design-Copy/)
[image]

**Back to your device**

Now, you can even see at the bottom of your device that it does unhinge and open up, due to the shape of the wood, and you can see the white mark on the wood where the rack collides with the rest of the structure.

**Just to be 100% sure**

Just to be 100% sure you could simply email the hotel with the photo and ask them, then let us know which answer was correct.

Comment: This doesn't really look like it would be a functional clothes drying rack though?  It opens to the side, not the bottom, and there's no airflow -- any clothes you hang on the top would collide with the ones below.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I emailed the hotel concerned asking what it was, but am yet to receive a reply. If they do reply, i shall let you know what they say.

Comment: The one in the picture is OBVIOUSLY not a drying rack as you would not mount 10-15 wet things basically on top of each other in a semi-circle.   This is a drying rack yet looks nothing like the picture in the question.